# Fourier transform on commutators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm having trouble with answering the following question:

> Use the Fourier transform to compute the commutator $$[x,|D_x|^\alpha], \alpha > 0.$$ Here, $|D_x|^\alpha$ is rigorously viewed as a Fourier multiplier (I believe), and $\alpha$ is a multi-index.

Please no full solutions! Just hints. I have already done some examples. Mainly, I am wondering:

1. Why is the Fourier transform even needed to solve this problem?
2. Is there a way in which this simplifies nicely?
3. Is there any way to write this other than just a sum of convolutions?

Comment: How do you define $|D_x|$ in position space?  Is $\alpha$ an integer ?

Comment: @tippy2tina, $|D_x|$ is sometimes viewed as distributional derivative $D_x$ but rigorously viewed as a multiplier. $\alpha$ is a multi-index.

Comment: Fourier transform is a unitary operator, call it $U$.  Can you compute $UxU^*$ and $UD_xU^*$